# How to store multiple data into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a profile page where user can edit their profile, I have provided them a skill form where they can enter skill name & percentage of how much you are perfect in it like->

```
Skill1 percentage 86%  Add more
```

this add more button adds input field dynamically

So now when i try to save this data here is what i get in $_POST

```
$_POST['skill'];
$_POST['percentage'];
```

i tried adding them into array so that i can save it to database but because of multiple dynamic field it get messy & then here is what i receive in array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Photoshop
    [1] => 55%
    [2] => PHP
    [3] => 35%
)
```

How can i easily know that this percentage is of this skill

Sometimes array looks like

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 55%
        [1] => Photoshop
        [2] => PHP
        [3] => 35%
    )
```

So how can i store dynamic field data into array so that later on it can be shown properly to the user

Comment: I guess the values are separated in those two `$_POST` values?!

Comment: @Rizier123 $_POST['skill']; got skill name & $_POST['percentage']; got only percentage

Comment: How are you sending your data from client side?

Comment: There we go then you already have the values separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set an array of fields in your form if you want to pass multiple values, like:

```
<input type="text" name="skills[]">
<input type="text" name="percentage[]">
```

and then in your php script:

```
foreach($_POST['skills'] as $index => $value) {
  $skills[$value] = $_POST['percentage'][$index];
}
```

assuming that skills and percentage are arrays with the same size.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array format that you like:

```
<input name='skill[0]'>
<input name='percentage[0]'>
<input name='skill[1]'>
<input name='percentage[1]'>
```

That will give you two arrays where the indexes match, for example:

```
(
    [skills] => Array
        (
            [0] => Photoshop
            [1] => Word
        )
)
```

And:

```
(
    [percentage] => Array
        (
            [0] => 65%
            [1] => 90%
        )
)
```

You could then use `array_combine($_POST['skills'], $_POST['percentage'])` to get something like:

```
Array(
        [Photoshop] => 65%
        [Word] => 90%
     )
```

You could use `name='skill[]` and `name='percentage[]` to create them dynamically instead of using numeric indexes, but if you ever try to do this with checkboxes it won't work as you may think.

Comment: It would do that also if you just use `name='skill[]' and `name='percentage[]` and be far simpler and more flexible

Comment: actually I'm using x editable plugin which edits input field at its place, so all the request is send individually

Comment: You'll need to update your question with how you create/name form elements and how the array actually looks and what you need or think you need.